# Calculate the probability of an event occurring AT LEAST x times over n trials?

Tags: probability, statistics

Forgive me if this is simple, but I've been twisting around this problem for a bit.

I know how to calculate if a given event happens *exactly* $x$ times over $n$ trials (where $p$ is the probability of the event occurring during a single trial):

$$p^x (1-p)^{n-x}$$

It seems like I could get the result of it occurring *at least* $x$ times by doing a sum...

$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-x} p^{x+q}  (1-p)^{n-(x+q)}$$

... But I'm assuming there's a simpler way, mathematically, to go about calculating this.  Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Your calculation of the event occurring exactly $x$ times is not right. There are multiple ways of the event occurring exactly $x$ times. Perhaps they occurred in the first $x$ trials, or perhaps the last $x$ trials, or ....

Comment: @Jeff, since you were interested, click "edit" to see the code for the math formatting

Comment: @angryavian Yep, looking over it now.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No simpler general formula than
$$\sum_{k=x}^{n}{n\choose k} p^{k}  (1-p)^{n-k}$$
Of course, if $n$ and $x$ go to infty, this is another story. For example, if $n\to\infty$, $x\to\infty$, and $x/n\to r$ for some fixed $r$ in $[0,1]$, then the sum converges to $1$ for every $r\lt p$, to $\frac12$ for $r=p$, and to $0$ for every $r\gt p$.

**Edit (to answer a comment):** Recall that $0!=1$ hence, in the sum above, the $k=n$ term is
$$
{n\choose n} p^{n}  (1-p)^{n-n}=1\cdot p^n\cdot(1-p)^0=p^n.
$$

Comment: What happens in this formula when `n = k`?  I'm not intimately familiar with the `choose` notation, but it seems like you'll be dividing by zero at that point?

Comment: No. See Edit. $ $

Comment: Ah, of course, I'm an idiot.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Asking is the way to learn, ain't it?

Answer (score 4):

The formula you are using is the same as 1 minus the [cumulative binomial distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function). If you are have a calculator/programming-language you can use that, without doing any iterative calculations yourself.

Cumulative binomial distribution function is **at most k events**

$$\texttt{atMost}(k,n,p) = \texttt{cumBinomDist}(k,n,p) \\
 = \Pr(X \le k) = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor k \rfloor} {n\choose i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$

So if you want to find the probability of **at least x events** you do

$$\texttt{atLeast}(x,n,p) = 1 - \texttt{cumBinomDist}(\texttt{ceil}(x) - 1,n,p) \\
 = 1 - \Pr(X \le \lceil x\rceil - 1) = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{\lceil x\rceil - 1} {n\choose i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i} \\
 = \sum_{i=\lceil x \rceil}^{n} {n\choose i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i} = \Pr(X \ge x) \\
$$

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is correct, but as David Mitra pointed out, you are undercounting the number of ways you can get $x$ events in $N$ trials. You need to multiply by $N \choose x$ then your approach will work. Its a discrete sum, so there is no shortcut as there would be with integrals.