# What is the probability of an event occurring k times over AT MOST n trials?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to do a mini project to calculate a rough percentage chance of a baseball team winning a series based on their and their opponent's winning percentage (Bill James' log5 formula for anyone interested). However this formula only gives the percentage chance of winning one game. Assume that the probability of winning the game is p = .7 for simplicity which doesn't change as more games are played, n = 7 at most, and k = 4 exactly. I have seen the below linked question which answers the question of "at least k times over n trials."

[Calculate the probability of an event occurring AT LEAST x times over n trials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684899/)

But if you are familiar with baseball and other sports play offs, you have to win a certain number of games in a series to progress, ie there is a chance that 'n' is less than its maximum. Is this fundamentally different from the linked problem, if so how would the formula to answer it change.

Edit: Using the idea from Michael's answer has show a pattern

$\sum_{x=1}^{k}\binom{n-x}{k-x}*(1-P)^{k-x}*(P)^k$

Where n is the max number of games in the series and k is the number of wins needed. The terms iterate in this pattern until k-x = 0.

Comment: The above formula looks good (assuming $n=2k-1$).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply list all possible outcomes associated with Team A winning the 7-game series:

Group 0: 
AAAA

Group 1: 
BAAAA, 
ABAAA, 
AABAA, 
AAABA

Group 2: 
BBAAAA, 
BABAAA, 
…

and so on.

Note that I am grouping in a way where Group $i$ means that team B wins $i$ times.  You will notice that outcomes in the same group have the same probability, so it reduces to just counting the number of outcomes in each group.

You can do a more general calculation for an $n$-game series (perhaps assuming $n$ is odd), in which case you need to find a formula for the coefficients associated with each group.